# How to add strings in the file at the end of all lines

Tags: python

I am trying to download files using python and then add lines at the end of the downloaded files, but it returns an error:

```
f.write(data + """<auth-user-pass>
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

**Edit:** Thanks, it works now when I do this b"""< auth-user-pass >""", but I only want to add the string at the end of the file. When I run the code, it adds the string for every line.

I also tried something like this but it also did not work: f.write(str(data) + "< auth-user-pass >")

here is my full code:

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def download_url(url):
    print("downloading: ", url)
    # assumes that the last segment after the / represents the file name
    # if url is abc/xyz/file.txt, the file name will be file.txt
    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("/") + 1
    file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]

    save_path = 'ovpns/'

    complete_path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
    print(complete_path)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(complete_path, 'wb') as f:
            for data in r:
                f.write(data + """<auth-user-pass>
username
password
</auth-user-pass>""")

    return url

servers = [
    "us-ca72.nordvpn.com",
    "us-ca73.nordvpn.com"
]

urls = []
for server in servers:
    urls.append("https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/files/ovpn_legacy/servers/" + server + ".udp1194.ovpn")

# Run 5 multiple threads. Each call will take the next element in urls list
results = ThreadPool(5).imap_unordered(download_url, urls)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Comment: `f.write(data + b"""<auth-user-pass>` you are missing a b in front of the string.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but I only want to add the string at the end of the file. When i run the code, it adds the string for every line.

Comment: Then reopen the file at the end of your code and add the line there instead of inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thanks, it works now when I do this b"""< auth-user-pass >""", but I only want to add the string at the end of the file. When I run the code, it adds the string for every line.

Try this:

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def download_url(url):
    print("downloading: ", url)
    # assumes that the last segment after the / represents the file name
    # if url is abc/xyz/file.txt, the file name will be file.txt
    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("/") + 1
    file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]

    save_path = 'ovpns/'

    complete_path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)
    print(complete_path)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(complete_path, 'wb') as f:
            for data in r:
                f.write(data)

    return url

servers = [
    "us-ca72.nordvpn.com",
    "us-ca73.nordvpn.com"
]

urls = []
for server in servers:
    urls.append("https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/files/ovpn_legacy/servers/" + server + ".udp1194.ovpn")

# Run 5 multiple threads. Each call will take the next element in urls list
results = ThreadPool(5).imap_unordered(download_url, urls)
with open(complete_path, 'ab') as f:
    f.write(b"""<auth-user-pass>
username
password
</auth-user-pass>""")
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using binary mode, `encode` your string before concat, that is replace

```
            for data in r:
                f.write(data + """<auth-user-pass>
username
password
</auth-user-pass>""")
```

using

```
            for data in r:
                f.write(data + """<auth-user-pass>
username
password
</auth-user-pass>""".encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

You open the file as a write in binary.
Because of that you cant use normal strings like the comment from @user56700 said.
You either need to convert the string or open it another way(ex. 'a' = appending).

Im not completly sure but it is also possible that the write binary variant of open the data of the file deletes. Normally open with write deletes existing data, so its quite possible that you need to change it to 'rwb'.

Comment: @Ppap Use open with 'ab', then you dont need to open it again. 
I cant comment on the post.